# Wide-character string converted from multibyte string using MultiByteToWideChar print and write to file error

Tags: winapi

I can print the wide-character string correctly, writing to text file is also OK, using the following code:

```
const wchar_t wcs[] = L"Hello大家好";
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
wprintf(L"%ls", wcs);
FILE *pf;
const wchar_t _FileName[] = L"wcs.txt";
pf = _wfopen(_FileName, L"a, ccs=UTF-8");
fwprintf(pf, L"%ls", wcs);
fflush(pf);
fclose(pf);
```

But I need to convert the multibyte string to wide-character string, using `MultiByteToWideChar`, and than print or write to text file, error occurred, the result displayed or the text file is all messy code. My code is below.

```
const char cs[] = "Hello大家好";
wchar_t lpWideCharStr[64];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, cs, 0, lpWideCharStr, 64);
wprintf(L"%ls", lpWideCharStr);
FILE *pf;
pf = _wfopen(_FileName, L"a, ccs=UTF-8");
fwprintf(pf, L"%ls", lpWideCharStr);
fflush(pf);
fclose(pf);
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using char array to store Chinese characters, the Chinese characters have been destroyed. In addition, if `cbMultiByte` is 0, the `MultiByteToWideChar` will fail.

Comment: Is that Chinese characters in a char array be encoded as multibyte characters? When I write `const char cs[] = "Hello大家好";printf("%s", cs);`, all characters can be displayed correctly in the console, and Visual Studio would show a tip that the `"Hello大家好"` is of type `char [12]`, witch means each Chinese character uses 2 bytes.@StriveSun-MSFT

Comment: `CP_ACP` need not be the same as the execution character set. The first argument to `MultiByteToWideChar` must match the input encoding. We don't know what that encoding is. It is expected that the developer writing the code does (that's you).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

bool ConvertToWideFromUTF8orACP(char* strData, wchar_t* w_strData, int w_strDataLen)
{
    int nSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, strData, -1, w_strData, w_strDataLen);
    if (nSize == 0)
    {
        nSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, strData, -1, w_strData, w_strDataLen);
    }    
    return nSize - 1;     
}

int main()
{
    char cs[] = "Hello大家好";
    printf("%s\n", cs);
    wchar_t* lpWideCharStr = new wchar_t[sizeof(cs)];
    memset(lpWideCharStr, 0, sizeof(cs));
    int nSize = ConvertToWideFromUTF8orACP(cs, lpWideCharStr,sizeof(cs));
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    if (nSize > 0)
    {
        wprintf(L"%s", lpWideCharStr);
    }   
    FILE* pf;
    pf = _wfopen(_FileName, L"a, ccs=UTF-8");
    fwprintf(pf, L"%ls", lpWideCharStr);
    delete[] lpWideCharStr;
    fflush(pf);
    fclose(pf);
}
```

Thanks @Remy Lebeau for help:)

Comment: The name `MakeUTF8Compatible()` is a bit misleading, something more like `ConvertToWideFromUTF8orACP()` would be more accurate :) Also, you are risking a buffer overflow by not validating `nSize` doesn't exceed `_countof(lpWideCharStr)` if `strData` is long. Granted, that is not the case in this particular example, but if this code is intended to be reused, then either dynamically allocate `lpWideCharStr`, or restrict `nSize`.

Comment: Some other bugs I see in this code: if `strData` points to a valid UTF-8 string, the `CP_UTF8` check is not actually converting the UTF-8 string into the `w_strData` buffer, only calculating the *length* of the `wchar_t` buffer. An actual conversion is being performed only for the `CP_ACP` case. Also, `lpWideCharStr` is being allocated with `new[]`, but is being deallocated with `delete` rather than `delete[]`, which is a mismatch causing *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You would need something more like this instead: `int ConvertToWideFromUTF8orACP(char* strData, wchar_t* w_strData, int w_strDataLen) { int nSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, strData, -1, w_strData, w_strDataLen); if (nSize == 0) nSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, strData, -1, w_strData, w_strDataLen); return nSize-1; }` ... `wchar_t* lpWideCharStr = new wchar_t[sizeof(cs)]; ... int nSize = ConvertToWideFromUTF8orACP(cs, lpWideCharStr, sizeof(cs)); ... if (nSize > 0) { wprintf(L"%*s", nSize, lpWideCharStr); } ... delete[] lpWideCharStr; ...`